# How to customize Edit-Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I already had a post that lead to this question but now I isolated one problem and so its better to make a new clean post :

Symfony 2.1.3 with jordillonch/CrudGeneratorBundle

I used this CrudGenerator on an entity in which I have 2 timestampable fields that need to be updated automatically :
I installed Gedmo for the timestampable funtionnality.

The fields are :

cree_le (in english created_at) : @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")

and modifiele (in english updated_at) - @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")

The problem is that I want to customize the form to show only the fields to update by the user.
When I use the not customized edit.html.twig using {{ form_widget(edit_form) }} the update is working but the values of updated_at are not changed because the old value is submitted with the form.
I tried several things to customize the form but I did not yet find the solution.

This version of customized edit.html.twig is not working because the submitted form is not valid :

```
<form class="well" action="{{ path('employee_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.nom) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.nom) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.nom) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.email) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.telephone, 'Téléphone') }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.telephone) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.telephone) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.actif) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.actif) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.actif) }}
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="too_employeebundle_employee_cree_le" name="too_employeebundle_employee[cree_le]" value="{{ entity.creele|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="too_employeebundle_employee_modifie_le" name="too_employeebundle_employee[modifie_le]" value="{{ entity.modifiele|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}">
    {{ form_widget(edit_form._token) }}
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ 'views.edit.editbutton'|trans({}, 'JordiLlonchCrudGeneratorBundle') }}</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Sure I'm doing something wrong but who could tell me how to go on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove cree_le and modifiele from your Form Class and dont render them on your template.
Then let Timestampable do his job! when you create something the cree_le value will be automatic set. When you change something the modifiele value will be automatic set too.